# Transferring data from one server to another in php

Tags: php

I want to transfer 10 user details from my server database to another server.The other server can call a php page (in my sever) which can supply the needed 10 user details.This should happen in such a way that a user using the site must not understand that the data is coming from another server.

Answer (score 1):

I will recommend using WebService for this purpose. In the Server `A` (provider) you will code this webservice to serve the users as requested by server `B`(consumer), So you will be able to consume the services provided by `A` at any time and being transparent for the USER.

[image]

---

### References:

- [WebService](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service)
- [XML-RPC](http://www.xmlrpc.com/)
- [SOAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP)

Answer (score 0):

You can implement JSON-RPC server and client.